# php - telegram bot message width

Tags: php, yii2, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

currently I'm working on a telegram bot in php and Yii2 framework. I want to send a message that has a fixed width in telegram. if i send "Hi!" it should fill a line like this image:
[image]

is it possible? I want the spaces after message so `<br>` wont do that and breaks the line right after the word 'Hi'. can I do this without `<code>` tag? because this tag make the message like a line of `code`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White space(s) and newline(s) at the two ends of the string are trimmed for a good reason. So, it is not possible to send the text with space or newline character(s) at any of the two ends, though you can put spaces at the end of the lines before the last character that's neither a space nor a newline.

**Update #1**
There is a trick though. You can add [Zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) as the text to a `<a>` tag with empty `href` after any number of spaces you want. So the essential params for [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method will be:

```
$text = 'hi‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌                           <a href="">&#8204;</a>';
$chat_id = <your chat_id>;
$parse_mode = 'HTML';
```

[image]

Comment: actually its not the perfect way, i think i was so excited!! :( its fine in telegram desktop but when you look at your android phone there are characters like | (pipeline character) in the message. i think they are Zero-width non-joiners. but its better than nothing. if there is anyway to hide them i'll be appreciate it

Comment: The screenshot I shared is from my android phone and there is nothing like a pipeline character. Can you share the code you are using to send such a message?

Comment: The pipeline character may be on a specific device whose font may not be handling the `&zwnj;` properly, even though it's a non printable character. You should check on another device. I used my Moto G4 Plus.

Comment: thanks I got the problem. my android phone is LG optimus L5. the problem is with my phone's fonts. I sent the message to a nokia_x2 and it was clear there. thanks guys.